# Disable all clickable links once 1 link has been clicked in jquery

Tags: jquery, list, button, removeall

I have a set of links:

```
<div id="dd" class="mywrap-dropdown-2" tabindex="2">Select
    <ul class="dropdowner" id="coll-filter">
        <li><a href="#">Black</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">White</li>
        <li><a href="#">Blue</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If clicked the link "White" then my links "Black" and "Blue" would no longer be clickable.

This is what I have but does not work:

```
$( '.dropdowner' ).on( 'click', 'li', function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();  
    $(".dropdowner li a").not(this).removeAttr("href")
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`unbind()` to unbind all the click events associated with that class

```
 $('.dropdowner').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).text().indexOf('White') > -1) {
        alert('Clicked Link with White..')
        $('.dropdowner a').not(this).unbind();
    } else {
        alert('Other Links Cliked');
    }
});​
```

Try this .. This will remove the click event for other links when the link with Black  is clicked..

[CHECK FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/RfDnF/)

Answer (score 2):

Your markup is inavlid, you have unclosed anchor links:

```
<li><a href="#">White  </li>
<li><a href="#">Blue   </li>
```

Note that in your code `this` refers to the `li` elements not anchor links, you should select anchor links instead of `li` elements.

```
$( '.dropdowner' ).on( 'click', 'a', function( e ) {
```

or:

```
$(".dropdowner li").not(this).find('a').removeAttr("href")
```